# having some issues with curl

Tags: php, curl

```
    <?php
$email = "";
$password = "";


function searchstring($string_to_search,$string_start,$string_end)
     {
      if (strpos($string_to_search,$string_start)===false)
          return false;
        if (strpos($string_to_search,$string_end)===false)
          return false;
       $start=strpos($string_to_search,$string_start)+strlen($string_start);$end=strpos($string_to_search,$string_end,$start);
        $return=substr($string_to_search,$start,$end-$start);
      return $return;   
            }

//curl get
function curl_get($ch, $url, $cookiefile) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    return $data;
}

//curl post

function curl_post( $ch, $url, $cookiefile, $post) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   return $data;
}

//cookie file
$cookiefile = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();



//get url to grab GALX to login
$data = curl_get($ch, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?uilel=3&service=youtube&passive=true&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252Findex&hl=en_US&ltmpl=sso", $cookiefile);

//grab galx token needed to login
preg_match('/name="GALX"\s*value="(.*?)"/', $data, $galx);


//login
$thegalx = $galx[1];

                             $post_elements=array('ltmpl'=>'sso',
                             'continue'=>'http://www.youtube.com/signin?action_handle_signin=true&nomobiletemp=1&hl=en_US&next=%2Findex',
                             'next'=>'/',
                             'service'=>'youtube',
                             'uilel'=>3,
                             'ltmpl'=>'sso',
                             'hl'=>'en_US',
                             'ltmpl'=>'sso',
                             'GALX'=>$thegalx,
                             'Email'=>$email,
                             'Passwd'=>$password,
                             'PersistentCookie'=>'yes',
                             'rmShown'=>1,
                             'signIn'=>'Sign in',
                             'asts'=>false,
                            );



$login = curl_post($ch, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth", $cookiefile, $post_elements);






//auth url
$data = curl_get($ch, "https://www.google.com/accounts/CheckCookie?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252Findex&hl=en_US&service=youtube&ltmpl=sso&chtml=LoginDoneHtml", $cookiefile);

//grab auth url
$authurl=html_entity_decode(urldecode(str_replace('\x', '%', searchstring($data,'location.replace("','"'))));
//print_r($authurl);



//hit auth url to login
curl_get($ch, $authurl, $cookiefile);


//$ch = curl_init();

//$data = curl_get($ch, "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBqVfmWM1og", $cookiefile);
//print $data;
//doesnt work

// youtube 
$datayoutube = curl_get($ch, "http://www.youtube.com/", $cookiefile);
print_r($datayoutube);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Hi,

I have been able to successfully login to youtube by grabbing the GALX value. When I print out the contents of http://youtube.com which is at the bottom of the code, it shows fine and it shows I am logged in.. but if I were to print out the contents of a video url (commented out below in the code) the page is just blank and white.. this is driving me crazy, anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: If the question is sorted, you can use the delete link to the bottom.

Comment: ok, am I the only one who saw this post turn into 'oooo ok okfiewrjtoeij'?

Comment: @jomanlk no, the OP edited it.

Comment: try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); as it may be redirecting

Comment: and when using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION make sure php is allowing it. things like safe mode could disable it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems ive had is with headers, postfields and cookies. Although it seems you have the cookies part of it sorted out, make sure you use LiveHTTPHeaders (an extension of Firefox) to sniff and see what additional headers are sent across and whether or not any more post data is sent through hidden forms etc.

Additional cookies used also show up in this. Although the curl SETOPT_COOKIEJAR takes care of cookies mostly, cookie management is a bit difficult because of this automation.

So make sure u double check the info sent across when loading a video page on youtube after loggin in and add those fields to curl.
Good Luck.